# How to use PeekMessage to check ALL messages in the queue, without removing them

Tags: delphi

This seems simple, but I'm pretty sure it's impossible.

I want to check all messages in the WM queue at a given time, but I do not want to process any message (PM_NOREMOVE). The problem is if I:

```
while PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0 PM_NOREMOVE)
     # do something with msg
```

I'll get stuck there forever.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, pass something other than `0,0` to [arguments 2, 3 and 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew).  You also seem to be missing an argument...

Comment: A `PM_NOREMOVE` loop will not work, as `PM_NOREMOVE` can only peek at the 1st message in the queue. You have to actually remove messages in order to see other messages in the queue. Why don't you want to remove messages?  What is the actual goal here? Please provide more details.

Comment: Depending on what you want to check, you may want to check GetQueueStatus.

Comment: I want to just check what messages are in the queue, nothing else.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm debugging some ancient code base, trying to figure out what's causing a crash in the field (no we can't reproduce, no we can't remote debug), so I've been tasked with logging the message queue at time of a crash.

Comment: @MrDysprosium Then why do you care about not removing messages?  Just flush the queue and log it.  You're crashing at this point anyway, presumably, so you don't really care whether the application gets those messages any more, no?

Comment: Sorry, it's stalling, there's a 15ish second stall. I don't wish to flush the queue.

My bad for poorly explaining the scenario, I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: Well, then logging the message queue is unlikely to help.  If the main thread is stalling it should be pretty obvious what is overwhelming it.  Either you have long running code living on the main thread or something is flooding the queue with messages faster than they can be processed.  A performance profiler seems like the better tool for this job, to be honest.

Comment: A message in the queue yet to be retrieved can't stall anything.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Indeed - it will, in fact, be the previous message which is presently causing the freeze.  To find which one, attach debugger, hit pause, look at the top of the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

PeekMessage allows you to look at the message and either squash it or dispatch it yourself, but there's no way to look at anything other than the first message on the queue.

This is by design - the queued messages need to be processed in the order they are received.

However, what you **can** do is look at all queued messages before dispatching them which may well allow you to do what you want but requires a different code structure.

Bear in mind that only messages in your queue will be seen, a message that's directly dispatched using SendMessage will not be in the queue so you won't see it - for that you may want to use a Windows Hook or something like that.

Comment: This isn't strictly true.  By passing arguments to the message filter parameters in PeekMessage you can find the first message of a *specific type*, even if it isn't the first message in the queue.  For example, if the first message is WM_CHAR but the second is WM_MOUSEMOVE you can filter to get the first mouse message, ignoring keyboard messages, etc.  You cannot peek any other mouse messages beneath that, however.